# How to parsing a image with user page id without submit button by jquery from

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**My Total process:**
My user can upload their profile cover image. So click upload button and select image, the image will be display and click to save.

Now I cannot parsing the **user page id** in `upload file`. So how to parsing ID by Jquery and Get this ID at php file.

My form:

```
//here data-id= user pageid that i want to parsing with image
//How to parsing this pageid at upload file

   <form id="bgimageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
       <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="bgphotoimg" class="custom-file-input" data-id="<? $page_user_info['id']; ?>">
   </form>
```

JQuery:

```
  //This script display image after selection.

  $('body').on('change','#bgphotoimg', function(){

  var pageid   =  $(this).attr('data-id');

  $("#bgimageform").ajaxForm({target: '#cover',
      beforeSubmit:function(){},
      success:function(){
         $("#bgimageform").hide();
      },
  error:function(){

  } }).submit();
  });
```

upload.php

```
// how to get that parsing id , is it right way?

if(isset($_POST['pageid']) && isset($_FILES['photoimg'])){
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

$pageid = $_POST['pageid'];

etc. others upload process.
```

Comment: Adding <input type="hidden" name="pageid" value="<? $page_user_info['id']; ?>"> not work also.

Comment: are you getting the value of the `$_FILES['photoimg']`?. try adding this line `echo $_POST;`  before the if statement in `upload.php` and see what's inside post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden field inside the form to pass the id to the php file

```
<form id="bgimageform" method="post" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">

    <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="bgphotoimg" class="custom-file-input" 
        data-id="<?php echo $page_user_info['id']; ?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" 
        value ="<?php echo $page_user_info['id']; ?>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Either your page_id is empty or your action path is invalid. You should be able to to echo your $_POST['page_id'];

Comment: Page id valid. you also look at my question "without submit button" at top. Thank you.

Comment: First try it with a submit button then simulate it.

Comment: A simple mistake, just place echo in php here: value ="<? echo $page_user_info['id']; ?>"/> working well. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can add it like that :

```
      data: { pageid: pageid },
```

you can see the doc about the data option [here](https://github.com/malsup/form/)